# Delay function on form field change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a relatively simple piece of code here.  I'm trying to delay `removeAttr` for 5 seconds after a checkbox is clicked, using `change()`.

I can get the `removeAttr` to work instantly on change, or the `setTimeout` to work on page load, but not in combination of the two.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="human"> I am a human
<input type="file" disabled name="file" id="file" />  

$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#human').change(

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#file').removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 5000));

    });
```

[Here is a complimentary JSFiddle of my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dt7q/).

Thanks guys and girls.

Comment: Missing name attribute for #human. Extra `)` after 5000, missing `function(){` after `change(`

Comment: shouldn't you be toggling instead of deleting the attribute. What happens when a user selects and then deselects? In that case use @A. Wolff's answer and check if the prop is true and set false. else set true.

Comment: That may be the case for some similar instances.  However my primary purpose is to prevent spam bots from uploading stuff in that field.  I will think about making it toggle.  Could bots check and uncheck?

Comment: So are you basing this implementation on the premise that bots can't wait for 5 seconds? It may be flawed in a longer term. If its some sensitive data, I'd suggest using captchas or some other verification systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript does not seem to be right. To achieve this you should handle change function appropriately

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#human').change(function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
            $('#file').removeAttr("disabled");
        }, 5000);
    })
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6JqYd/)

Comment: Just one thing `$('document')` will return empty object, even pseudo jQuery ready event handles it, using a promise, it should be bound to `document` object

Comment: I guess I initially had my function to remove the attribute, and thought just sticking setTimeout on the beginning of it would delay it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `delay()` by putting relevant code in queue:

*{document is an object, not an element type}*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#human').one('change', function () {
        $('#file').delay(5000).queue(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
});
```

### DEMO

Comment: I tried delay as well, but not with the queue.  I did not know about queue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have misunderstood you, but you call `setTimeout` instead of setting it as the handler. You can e.g. put the code in separate function-handler and set this function as the event handler:

```
var myFunc = function () {
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#file').removeAttr("disabled");
   }, 1000);
};

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#human').change(myFunc);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE6W8/)